# multiple excel columns into a two column file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with multiple columns in the following format:

```
name_1      name_2  name_3  
name_1  name_4  name_5  name_6
```

This stands for name_1 cooperates with name_2 and name_3, name_2 cooperates with name_3, etc
So I need to create a new excel file that will have all the cooperations, e.g

```
name_1  name_2
name_1  name_3
name_2  name_3
name_1  name_4
name_1  name_5
name_1  name_6
name_4  name_5
name_4  name_6
name_5  name_6
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Create a copy of the file??? Sorry, I might be misunderstanding what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need VBA to do this.

If your data is like this,

[image]

Try out the below code,

```
Sub splitTable()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, x As Long
Sheets.Add.Name = "newSheet"
k = 1
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 2 To Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = x To Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 1) = Cells(i, x - 1)
        Sheets("newSheet").Cells(k, 2) = Cells(i, j)
        k = k + 1
    Next j
    Next x
Next i
End Sub
```

The code creates a new sheet and prints the formatted output,

[image]

Comment: @temelina Thats nice. Please mark my answer as correct to close this question. You can see that on the left side of my answer